# Implications of the loss function on the distribution y | x?

Tags: regression, distributions, loss-functions

Suppose we are dealing with a standard regression problem. To make things simple we have a single predictor variable $x$ and a response variable $y$, and we also know:

1. The underlying **real** relationship between them is $y = x^2 + \eta$, with $\eta$ being noise.
2. $y \ | \ x \ $ follows a gamma distribution.

As far as I understand we have, on the one hand, the function that models how $y$ varies with $x$, $E(y \ | \ x)$; and, on the other hand, how the uncertainty around each fixed $x_0$ behaves, which would correspond here to a gamma distribution.

Say for example that I wanted to model this using a Generalized Linear Model. Then the appropriate link would be $g^{-1}(x) = x^2$, and the distribution, of course, gamma.

Now, in order to train a neural network or do gradient boosting we try to minimize a loss function. How would I translate the above knowledge to a loss function? In other words, How does one choose the loss function assuming the knowledge above?

Comment: There's some more development of the link between likelihoods and cross-entropy here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378274/how-to-construct-a-cross-entropy-loss-for-general-regression-targets

Answer (score 1):

Generalized linear models are fitted using [maximum likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms), so instead minimizing loss, we maximize the likelihood. So instead of minimizing something like squared error, you need to maximize the likelihood, or minimize negative likelihood, i.e.

$$
\operatorname{arg\,min}_\theta -\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \,\log f(y|x, \theta)
$$

where $f$ is the gamma probability density function in your case, and $\theta$ are the parameters.