# What is the MLE for regression machine learing models?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, loss-functions, train

From my understanding, in linear regression maximizing the log-likelihood function is equivalent to maximizing the negative MSE. But what about other common regression machine learning models specifically, regression trees and neural network? Does maximizing the negative MSE equivalent to maximizing the log-likelihood function?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I posted a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/557916/247274) late last year. // [Another related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/145902/247274)