# Negative KL Divergence estimates

Tags: regression, python, kullback-leibler, scipy, divergence

I was exploring the KL Divergence and came across some research about calculating it from samples. On stack-exchange, I found out that [minimising the KL Divergence is equivalent to minimising the Sum of squares in Linear Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477152/using-cross-entropy-for-regression-problems).

To explore this further, I tried to implement a OLS and Ridge regression model for the Boston Housing Data-set and calculated the KL Divergence as mentioned in the papers. This gave me inexplicable results.

Firstly, the KL Divergence was negative for the estimator from [Kullback-Leibler divergence estimation of continuous distributions](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4595271). And instead of being negative for the OLS fit from the actual responses, it was negative for the Ridge fit from the ground truth, which is just contrary to the theoretical case.(I interpret negative KL Divergence as the fitted values being so good that the estimator just gave negative values, and would have given zero if I had the actual Distribution instead of samples from it).

Is there a clean explanation why this is happening?

PS: Just to explore the multidimensional capabilities of the estimators, I also passed in the entire data-matrix with the response/fitted value appended instead of just the responses to the KL Divergence estimators.
This made the remaining 4 implementation of the estimator from
Based on my understanding, this assumes that there is an underlying probability distribution which generated all the values for the covariates and the responses, and we calculate the KL Divergence between these distributions. I thought that this should not change anything because if we go back to the equivalence between OLS and KL Divergence, I imagine this as having a bunch of zeroes tacked onto the sum does not make a difference.
Nevertheless, this experiment led to a negative value for all the four implementation of the estimator in the GitHub link.

Thus, coming back to the question posed earlier, how do I interpret the negative estimates of KL divergence, and why is it happening in this case.

References:

[Estimators coded in python](https://github.com/nhartland/KL-divergence-estimators)

[Pérez Estimator](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4595271)

[Paper for estimators coded in python](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4839047)

Results of calculation for uni-dimensional case

| Estimator | d_truth_ols | d_truth_ridge | d_ols_ridge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| skl_efficient | 0.05405258685484415 | 0.08663935806497296 | 0.04198067991782772 |
| scipy_estimator | 0.802908876382145 | 0.7347464259492821 | 0.6900877478021367 |
| naive_estimator | 0.05405258685484412 | 0.08663935806497293 | 0.04198067991782768 |
| skl_estimator | 0.05405258685484412 | 0.08663935806497293 | 0.04198067991782768 |
| perez | -0.06423632396883772 | 0.021712462670751664 | 0.05954526258402315 |

Results of calculations for multidimensional case (when I pass the entire data-matrix)-

| Estimator Name | KL(y_Ridge, y_Truth) | KL(y_OLS, y_Truth) | KL(y_Ridge, y_OLS) | KL(y_OLS, y_Ridge) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| skl_estimator | -0.12739426 | -0.22722966 | -0.24495304 | -0.41479071 |
| naive_estimator | -0.12739426 | -0.22722966 | -0.24495304 | -0.41479071 |
| skl_efficient | -0.12739426 | -0.22722966 | -0.24495304 | -0.41479071 |
| scipy_estimator | 7.73544109 | 6.74554664 | 7.61788232 | 6.55798559 |

Lastly, I just guess that the SciPy estimator is out of whack.
Thanks a lot!